# Запомнить старое положение вкладок TabControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Как запомнить старое положение вкладок в TabControl при каждом запуске программы.
***Мое решение
При закрытие программы запоминаю индекс каждой вкладки

```
3tab:0,1:1,ff2:2,newtab:3,Новый sdfsdf ываыва:4
```

header вкладка:индекс вкладки

Потом вызвываю метод, который проверяет изменения вкладок.

***В tabs нажодится массив с старым положением вкладок**

***В TabContol1 новые вкладки.**

```
       int PositionTabs(string[] tabs)
    {
        foreach (var item in tabs)
        {
            string[] oldtabs = item.Split(':');
            foreach (TabItem tbc in TabContol1.Items)
            {
                if(tbc.Header.ToString() == oldtabs[0])
                {
                    var tabControl = tbc.Parent as TabControl;
                    var tabNew = tabControl.Items.IndexOf(tbc);
                    if(tabNew != Convert.ToInt32(oldtabs[1]))
                    {
                        foreach (TabItem tbc2 in TabContol1.Items)
                        {
                            var tabControl2 = tbc2.Parent as TabControl;
                            int tabNew2 = tabControl.Items.IndexOf(tbc2);
                            if(tabNew2 == Convert.ToInt32(oldtabs[1]))
                            {
                                tabControl.Items.Remove(tbc2);
                                tabControl.Items.Insert(tabNew, tbc2);

                                tabControl.Items.Remove(tbc);
                                tabControl.Items.Insert(tabNew2, tbc);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

1 перемещение вкладки работает, но вот после чего появляется исключение `Коллекция была изменена; невозможно выполнить операцию перечисления`
Кто поможет, мб есть другое рещение, и я слишком намудрил с 3 циклами.

Comment: "Коллекция была изменена; невозможно выполнить операцию перечисления" - во время foreach нельзя вносить изменения в коллекцию, по которой идет проход. Наверное нужно создать копию, и в нее вставлять

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы делаете неправильно.
Вы не должны работать на уровне визуальных контролов, и пытаться создать их и переставить.

Правильный подход — ваши табы должны создаваться автоматически, через привязку `ItemsSource` к модели представления (VM). Последовательность табов при этом определяется последовательностью элементов в `ItemsSource`. Таким образом, если порядок элементов в VM правильный, то и табы будут автоматически в правильном порядке.

Comment: А нельзя задать индекс при добавления item'a в TeabControl?
`TabContol1.Items.Add(new TabItem() { Header = name, Content = grid });` - Так добавляю нове вкладки

Comment: @fangry: Не, вы должны добавлять не вручную, а через Binding. Тогда все проблемы уйдут.